# Proving the relationship between Gamma and Beta functions without Fubini theorem

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

is it possible to prove the identity
$$\forall x > 0,\ \forall y > 0,\quad B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and $B$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) without using the Fubini theorem (the standard proof using it and polar coordinates)?

It am looking for an elementary proof of this identity...

Comment: Shouldn't you define the Beta function in the first place?

Comment: Hint: you find a derivation without polar coordinates in the Wikipedia article you have referenced, paragraph "Relationship between gamma function and beta function"

Comment: The question of whether [@Dr.WolfgangHintze's link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) qualifies as a non-Fubini proof is left as an exercise for the reader... unless someone else addresses it.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze : in the Wikipedia article, paragraph "Relationship between gamma function and beta function", the two given proofs use Fubini theorem.

Comment: Ok, but you also spoke about polar coordinates… Anyway, coming back to my first comment: how do you define the two functions for which you wish to see a relationship?

Comment: Both $\Gamma$ and $B$ are defined in the usual way: $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$ and $B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} dt$ for all $x,y>0$. But if you have any proof using an alternative definition, it would be a great start.

Comment: 1) You should give the definitions to complete the OP. 2) In order to avoid coming too close to Fubini's theorem you should avoid definitions by integrals. You could use the well-known definition of $\Gamma$ as an infinite product, and the definition $B(x,y) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k-y}{k}\frac {1}{x+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k-x}{k}\frac {1}{y+k}$ which I remember from the good old times of the beginning of string theory.

Comment: An elementary proof for this relationship would immediately give an elementary proof for the gaussian integral, and since for centuries an elementary proof wasn't found for that integral, I don't expect there to be one for this relationship either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove the identity in a different way using Euler's infinite product representation of the gamma function,

$$\Gamma(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\Gamma_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!n^x}{(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+n)}$$

The beta function defined as $\displaystyle B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \, dt$ satisfies the recurrence relation

$$ \tag{1}B(x,y) = \frac{x+y}{y}B(x,y+1)$$

The proof of (1) involves integration by parts and can be furnished if desired. Applying (1) $n$ times we get

$$\tag{2}B(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1) \cdots (x + y + n)}{y(y+1) \cdots (y +n)}B(x,y+n+1)  \\ =\frac{\Gamma_n(y)}{\Gamma_n(x+y)}n^{x}B(x,y+n+1)$$

Note that

$$n^{x}B(x,y+n+1) = n^{x}\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y+n} \, dt,$$

and after changing variables with $s = nt$ we get

$$\tag{3}n^{x}B(x,y+n+1) = \int_0^ns^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{y+n} \, ds = \int_0^ns^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{y}\, ds $$

Substituting into (2) using (3) yields

$$\tag{4}B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma_n(y)}{\Gamma_n(x+y)}\int_0^ns^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{y}\, ds$$

By the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^ns^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{y}\, ds  =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty}s^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1-\frac{s}{n}\right)^{y}1_{[0,n]}\, ds  \\ = \int_0^\infty s^{x-1}e^{-s}\, ds ,$$

and, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Gamma_n(z) = \Gamma(z)$, upon taking the limit of both sides of (4) as $n \to \infty$ we obtain

$$B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}\int_0^\infty s^{x-1}e^{-s}\, ds = \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Comment: It seem more complicated to say an elementary proof. Your $\Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Gamma_n(x)$ is quite unclear to me. How did you get that?

Comment: @emonHR: That goes back to Euler’s original definition when $x$ is a positive integer and extends to all real $x$ not equal to $0$ or a negative integer.

Comment: Thanks that was the kind of stuff I was looking for.

Comment: @Héhéhé: You're welcome.